# Рисование деревьев на Python

Tags: python, дерево

написал код для бинарного дерева, искал методы как его визуализировать в окнах, причем как графы, с узлами и прочим, достойного ответа не нашел, обращаюсь к гуру сего форума за помощью, а именно за советом, где лучше на Python делать деревья, причем графообразные.

Comment: не уверен, но возможно это вам как то поможет - [ссылка](https://habr.com/ru/company/ods/blog/464715/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, с помощью Graphviz можно построить деревья и вывести картинку этого куда надо, для этого надо скачать сам Graphviz с официального сайта, установить его, в python скрипте прописать 
`import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'`
вместо моего пути указать ваш путь, и написать свой собственный алгоритм построения этих деревьев.

Answer (score 2):

Для визуализации любых графов (не больших объемов) можно использовать [Graphviz](https://graphviz.org/). Для python есть API [graphviz](https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/), через которое можно задать и нарисовать граф. Рисовать бинарные деревья через этот инструмент так же возможно, по умолчанию они получаются не очень красивые, но есть возможность [написать скрипт к graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10902745/3422245), который сделает отображение бинарных деревьев правильным.

Comment: Это хорошо, но я не нашел достойного гайда , или документации по сему творению, с официального источника всё печально, я не могу вывести саму картинку графа, а мне она как раз таки и нужна

Comment: @antipups Тогда вам следует задать вопрос о том, как вывести картинку графа в окне, используя graphviz и python

Comment: Хорошо. картинку вывести я смог, а сам алгоритм ужасен. я не могу придумать нормальный алгоритм для рисовки этих деревьев, а мне ещё к тому же нужно задачу на удаление элемента с одним дочерним элементом.

Comment: @antipups Это тоже тема для нового вопроса, в котором вы можете описать ваш код, и задать вопрос про интересующие вас проблемы этого кода